# Proof of a step of a lemma on the asymptotics of maximum likelihood where a Taylor expansion is used

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, taylor-series

I am trying to understand a proof of quite a long theorem that I report completely for the sake of completeness. 
This is From Jensen and Rahbek *Asymptotic Inference for Nonstationary GARCH* (2004).
My question is actually basic and only regards the Taylor expansion done in the proof so one can skip to the end if he wishes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

At the start of the proof through the mean value theorem $\lambda^*$ is proven to exist. Then a Taylor expansion is made.

$$\Big| \frac{\partial f(\lambda^*)}{\partial \lambda} \Big| = \Big| \sum_{i,j,l = 1}^k v_{1,i}v_{2,j} (\varphi_l - \varphi_{0,l}) \partial^3 \ell_T (\varphi_0 - \lambda^* (\varphi - \varphi_0))/ \partial \varphi_i \varphi_j \varphi_l  \Big|$$

I think he cuts it off after the second term, to be clear I write the Taylor expansion that I think he does in the univariate form:

$$ f(\lambda^*)+\frac {f'(\lambda^*)}{1!} (\varphi-\lambda^*)+ \cdots. $$

My questions that I think are all connected are:

1. Where does the first term go in the expansion? (where is $ f(\lambda^*)$ ?)
2. Why introduce $\lambda^*$ at all? (notice that condition A.3 of Lemma 1 does not involve $\lambda^*$)?
3. Why does equality hold in this Taylor expansion?

Comment: The series is not cut off in this exposition: it uses a [mean-value form of the remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_mean_value_forms_of_the_remainder) in Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! what would be the error function?

Comment: @whuber Also is the Cauchy form of the remainder being used? I still can't seem to calculate it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is the Lagrange form of Taylor's theorem with remainder (https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/taylors_thm/) I believe.

And it is an expansion of f(1) around f(0), ie $f(1)=f(0)+f'(\lambda^*).(1-0)$, for some $\lambda^*\in (0,1)$.

So hopefully it is clear that this explains your 3 questions.

Comment: But where does  $f(0) = v_2' [D^2 \ell_T( \varphi_0) ] v_2$  go? And if we are deriving with respect to $\lambda$ why is there the third derivative with respect to $\varphi$? Thanks by the way.

Comment: I think he is just taking the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ but why is it written with respect to $\varphi$ ? Can we chat so you can explain it to me?